# Is it worthwhile to add a "roll20" tag to the main list?

Tags: discussion, tags

My group has been using the browser-based Roll20 (https://app.roll20.net) platform pretty heavily lately. It provides voice and video chat, mapping tools, etc, and has been pretty instrumental in keeping our long-distance campaigns up and running when players end up living some distance away.

*I'm wondering whether it might be worth including a "roll20" tag to the main list.* This app has a ton of neat features and I understand that they have their own boards for discussing these, but I can see a potential market for more general questions about how best to incorporate this software into your game, and how to most effectively use it to keep long-running campaigns going even if the players disperse.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The tagging system here is emergent.  There is no master list.  You can just add new tags to your questions.  (Well, that does require 300 rep...).  Then if people use it, it'll stay, otherwise it will get auto deleted.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Apologies for being uninformed.

Answer (score 8):

If there are questions about Roll20, then yes. If not, then no.

Tags are added by any user with 300 reputation, if you ask a question and don't have the tags you need, then add them. If you don't have the reputation to add them, then please either comment or flag so they can be added for you.