# I think I just created the [roll20] tag; is it appropriate?

Tags: discussion, tags

I didn't notice we didn't already have a [roll20](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/roll20) tag for the pretty big virtual tabletop located at roll20.net.  I added a few tags to a new question and afterwards clicked the [roll20](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/roll20) tag to see the tag-wiki for it out of curiosity; and then noticed it not only didn't have a tag wiki, but it only had 1 question - the one I'd just added it to.

I will admit a complete lack of knowledge regarding tag making etiquette - should I undo my tag creation?

(This popped up in the similar questions list while I was writing, very much related:  [Is it worthwhile to add a "roll20" tag to the main list?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3346/is-it-worthwhile-to-add-a-roll20-tag-to-the-main-list))

---

Update:  After reading and re-reading other meta posts and the tag creation privilege, I believe the tag to be worthwhile and will go ahead and start making a tag-wiki for it and tagging existing appropriate questions, but I want to leave this question up so more experienced users can still weigh in and confirm my opinion or explain why I'm wrong.

Answer (score 10):

The tag creation process is totally dynamic, and for the most part, completely up to us.

The system intentionally makes transparent to you whether or not you're creating a new tag, and this is by design - new tags arise organically, and when they do, they make sense. Occasionally, tags do need to be removed and cleaned up, but this honestly doesn't happen with any real frequency.

In this case, the Roll20 service is a useful, effective, and clear categorization, and is a prefect candidate for a tag.

Comment: Indeed, I'm surprised one didn't already exist

Comment: @Phil I think it did actually, and then was removed as seeming unnecessarily specific for general "I'm using Roll20, how do I [general VTT thing]" questions. But with the recent questions on very specific Roll20 features, it seems well warranted now.